# Make a MariaDB view that includes a boolean

Tags: mysql, mariadb, sql-view

I created this view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vista_metadatos AS
SELECT m.*, f.archivo IS NOT NULL AS myBooleanColumn
FROM metadatos m
LEFT JOIN facturas f ON (m.uuid = f.uuid)
```

However `myBooleanColumn` is being returned as an `INT` and I want it to be a `Boolean` which in this case should be a `TINYINT`:

```
> desc vista_metadatos;
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                 | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| uuid                  | varchar(40)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| otherBooleanColumn    | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| myBooleanColumn       | int(1)       | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| ...                   | varchar(42)  | NO   |     |         |       |
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

From this `desc` I know that views can hold `TINYINT`, but how can I create a view that uses that condition as a `TINYINT`?

Comment: MySQL doesn't have a boolean type. Booleans are just integers that are always 0 or 1.

Comment: Yes, but you see, in the view the column is `int(1)` not `tinyint(1)`... so the result set metadata shows the column as an `INT` column... which messes up the way I handle that column on java

Comment: What difference does it make? The distinction between `INT` and `TINYINT` only matters for tables that are stored, since it can use less storage. Views aren't stored.

Comment: It does make a difference because of how the result set will be handled on my java backend

Comment: Then I think you may need to use a different database. MySQL doesn't give you enough control over expression types, you only have this control in table columns.

Comment: @Barmar I guess, however I will workaround it by checking the type and precision for the column, lets just hope I don't have any `INT(1)` not intended to be booleans in the databases I'll be working on

Comment: It's hard to imagine any use of `INT(1)` other than for booleans.

Comment: @LeedMx - Please elaborate on how Java has trouble with `INT`.

Comment: @RickJames I use `rs.getObject()` to generate an `Object[]` for each row in the result set, this generates a `TableModel` which treats each object according to `object.getClass()` so an `Integer` and a `Boolean` are treated completely different. I workaround it now by checking the precision. However the fact remains that the question is straightforward: How to get a Boolean in a view? not, How do I justify with you guys the fact that I need a `TINYINT(1)` instead of an `INT(1)`?

Comment: Consider filing a bug with MariaDB.

Answer (score 0):

You should not really care. A view does not actually store the data, so there is no overhead anyway. And you can use an `INT` that has `0`/`1` values just like you use a `BOOLEAN`.

As far as [the documentation states](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert), `BOOLEAN` (or `TINYINT()`) are not supported targets for casting. So althought that might not be satisfying from a pure intellectual point of view, you'll have to live with this...

Comment: The casting seems to be what I need but does not seem to work with that syntax.

Comment: @LeedMx: just rechecked the docs: this is actuallly not an option. But again - and as commented by Barmar too: what difference does it make?

Comment: Is just that I have a lot of java classes that parse the result as boolean or int accordingly based on the metadata or the result set... so having the column as tinyint would really help me out

Comment: I guess that I could check for the lenght of the column, after all this seems to be the only case that `INT(1)` is goind to be used

Answer (score 0):

CAST and CONVERT have no boolean, use an IF instead

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW vista_metadatos AS
SELECT 
  m.*
  ,IF(f.archivo IS NOT NULL, 'TRUE', 'FALSE') AS myBooleanColumn
FROM metadatos m
LEFT JOIN facturas f ON (m.uuid = f.uuid)
```

Comment: tried that but the column ends up as `VARCHAR`, and if i do `IF(f.archivo IS NOT NULL,TRUE,FALSE)` it goes back to `INT(1)`

Comment: yes, that is as stated before Tinyint and boolean are not supported, so use INT(1). I still after 15 year don't understand why we can not have a Boolean liek other rdms have, but that probably the answer, to use a commercial rdms

Comment: small tradeoffs for using open source, is cool though free software for the win!